# How to convert a five-digit output into multiple one-digit outputs?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to take an output with 5 digits in it (numbers 10000-99999), and I need them to be split apart into five one digit outputs. (12345 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). The process needs to be done in that order (5-digit output -> 5 1-digit output -> ...)

I currently have this as the base:

```
import random

num = random.randint(10000,99999)
print(num)
```

Step 1 is good, I just need Step 2.

I tried looking on GitHub for the proper usage of .split(), but I could not find what I needed. I also looked on a website called geeksforgeeks, but again, did not find an answer.
What I tried after GitHub fiasco:

```
import random

num = random.randint(10000, 99999)
num = num.split()
```

I just got an error from that, saying 'AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' '

What I tried after geeksforgeeks.org:

```
import random
num = random.randint(10000, 99999).split()
print(num)
```

I got another error, saying the same as before: 'AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' '

Comment: @mousetail How would I do that? Is it as simple as str(num = random.randint(#, #)?

Comment: that is very much XY problem - Instead of one 5-digi number and trying o split the digits, just generate five 1-digit randomly

Comment: You don't even need split, just do `list(str(num))`

Comment: The best place for checking the usage of python methods is python documentation itself (e.g. [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)). Not GitHub, unless of course you are using package hosted in it. GeeksforGeeks is not thoroughly curated and may be misleading for beginners.

Comment: @BrendanCarey - You cannot perform string operations on an integer, so convert the integer into a string, and the n perform the string operation. Your split operation isn’t complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unpack the string representation of your pseudo-random number and specify a separator as follows:

```
import random

num = random.randint(10_000, 99_999)

print(*str(num), sep=', ')
```

**Possible output:**

```
2, 7, 9, 5, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Decimal digits are just one of many possible representations of an integer. Luckily it's a popular one and is the representation created when you create a Python string. Once you create the string, it is naturally iterated digit by digit.

```
import random

num = random.randint(10000,99999)
for digit in str(num):
    # if the string represenation of the digit is okay
    print(digit)
    # if you really need it to be an integer 
    # (but note, print converts it to a string again)
    print(int(digit))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the number to str, then split the string symbol by symbol and then transform each element of the resulting list back to int.

```
num = random.randint(10000,99999)
print(
    list(map(int, list(str(num))))
)
```

Output:

```
[4, 9, 0, 4, 0]
```